# pip install package from url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

```
pip install http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/unreleased/4.x/BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz
```

this installs package bs4, and everything is ok. But if I add this line to requirements.txt

```
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/unreleased/4.x/BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz
```

and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

the output is

```
  Downloading/unpacking http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/unreleased/4.x/BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz (from -r requirements.txt (line 40))
  Downloading BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz (42Kb): 42Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/unreleased/4.x/BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz
```

but the package doesn't get installed.

```
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this. Works for me.

Comment: a) have you tried 'import BeautifulSoup' and b) have you checked the python path to see if BS was actually installed and c) are you using virtualenv or anything like that?

Comment: it is installed as bs4 package, since it is a 4.0 version. It is imported as BeautifulSoup in version 3.2

Comment: Ivan I've just tested here, and it worked alright. I installed with requirements.txt and tried to "import bs4" and it worked

Comment: you said that the `pip install http://....` worked, are you sure? did you try to `import bs4` ?

Comment: yes, it worked with url parameter. Now I tried to do this again, and install with requirements.txt also worked! Seems like the new version of pip supports it.

Comment: Wow... Because I’ve never tried this before (pip install <url.tar.gz>)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that this can happen if you have more than one interpreter installed and pip is using one (e.g., 2.6) and your python shell another (e.g., 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you are working with **portable software** or with **more than one** versions of Python / IDLE

what happens is that you can only install in the **default path**, otherwise you need to find a way to specifically install in the **required path**

*(for me when I used pip from the windows **cmd** did not work in pycharm but when used pip from pycharm worked)*