# How is Pip able to install packages by name or URL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I knew that you could install Python packages by name with pip, but I recently found out that you can [install Python packages by URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768624/pip-install-package-from-url). For example:

```
pip install http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/unreleased/4.x/BeautifulSoup-4.0b.tar.gz
```

How is Pip able to do this? What if a package name looks like a URL?

Comment: hint: pip is open source

Comment: When would a package name look like a URL?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Like Martijn Peters Pointed out, a module name really can't look like a URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, just check the source. Pip has a function in their downloads module to check if the name input looks like a URL.

```
def is_url(name):
    """Returns true if the name looks like a URL"""
    if ':' not in name:
        return False
    scheme = name.split(':', 1)[0].lower()
    return scheme in ['http', 'https', 'file', 'ftp'] + vcs.all_schemes
```

**Edit:** As @MartijnPieters pointed out, there are standards for what you can name a module, and putting a colon in the name isn't permitted.

If you are trying to put **http:** at the beginning of the name of your module, you're probably not writing software I want to download.

Comment: `http` *and a colon*. Pip has about 65 packages that start their name with `http`. None of them use a colon in the name (which isn't permitted anyway).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right. Or any other or any other protocol header for that matter.