# How to install python package from URL?

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I have built a python package by running the command-

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

This command creates 2 files in dist folder, which are as follows-

```
1. testpackage-0.0.0.tar.gz
2. testpackage-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I have uploaded these files to google drive, the folder structure looks like this-

```
testpackage
 |- testpackage-0.0.0.tar.gz
 |- testpackage-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I have created a shareable link to 'testpackage' folder on google drive. Let's say the link is 'https://drive.google.com/xyz123'

Now, I want to install this package using pip command. I want to do something like this-

```
pip install -i https://drive.google.com/xyz123
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea on how I can install a python package from a specific URL using pip command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install package from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768624/pip-install-package-from-url)